# Registering simulator runtime with CoreSimulator failed. while downloading IOS 17.0 SDK in Xcode 15.0

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have downloaded new version of xcode for ios 17.0 application updates. while downloading the process keeps stopping because of coresilulator failure.

Please give the solution to this error to download the IOS 17 SDK in Xcode 15.0.

Comment: Answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77133957/3507433

Comment: I answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77251040/12731334

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, it turns out I didn't have enough disk space. I had 17GB or so which I thought it was plenty but apparently not. Having 33GB free space indeed worked.

Comment: worked with 29 GB free storage.