# iOS 17.0 Simulator (21A328) Failed with HTTP status 400: bad request

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, http-status-code-400

I update from Xcode 15 beta to Xcode 15.

I wanted to install the iOS package and got this error:

[image: Screenshot]

I already reinstalled Xcode.

There are already newer versions on the Apple site than what is shown here. Is that maybe where the error comes from?

Comment: caught the same error. Xcode UX is awesome as ever

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try the link https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime/iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime.dmg.

You can download it manually from [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) and install it using instruction from *[Installing and managing Simulator runtimes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes)*

After downloading, run:

```
xcrun simctl runtime add iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime.dmg
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for my colleague. It's weird that I never ran into the error on Xcode 15 though. I think I had installed ios 17 beta pretty early on maybe that's why.

Comment: I got this error "SUIS premount dissented
the operation is not appropriate (kDAReturnNotPermitted)"

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by downloading the stimulator through the command line.

Just type this command in the terminal:

```
xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS
```

Comment: Re *"stimulator"*: This seems to be a write-only answer. What kind of stimulator?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue, because of storage issue. But I am using a [Apple M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) 256 GB and I can't able to reduce my storage because system data is 150 GB.

I just downloaded the runtime from Apple and ran the following command in the terminal after download. It worked.

```
xcrun simctl runtime add iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime.dmg
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by flushing the DNS. Try this:

1. Open the Terminal app
2. Enter `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`, enter your password if prompted
3. Enter `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
4. Reconnect your Wi-Fi / Ethernet connection

Or you can simply flush the DNS with CleanMyMac. Either method works just the same.

Comment: For me it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just sign in with your [Apple Developer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer) account to
Xcode → *Signing in & capabilities* → select *Team*,
and it starts your downloading again.
This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the suggested methods, but none of them worked for me.

So I did go to [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS/iPadOS)), and updated Xcode. After the update is done, running Xcode, it shows the list of simulators to install. Select iOS 17.0.

Then it works well.